# Output of multi-threaded program does not display correctlty

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe

I have written a program that has been troubled by the network. It was used in the multithreading. The problem is thread output. The program is mixed. And the output does not display correctly.

I have written two sample programs, neither of which work correctly.

**Program 1**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient,
  IdRawBase,IdRawClient, IdIcmpClient, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,StdCtrls,ExtCtrls;

type
  TPSThread=class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure execute; override;
end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
  Procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); Override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  PortG:Integer;
  HostG:string;
  FormG:TForm;
  WM_Msg_PS:DWORD;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TPSThread.execute;
var
  IcmpClient:TIdIcmpClient;
  TCPClient:TIdTCPClient;
  HostT:string;
  PortT:Integer;
  ActiveServer:Boolean;
begin
  inherited;
  HostT:=HostG;
  PortT:=PortG;

  IcmpClient:= TIdIcmpClient.Create();
  try
    with IcmpClient do
    begin
      ReceiveTimeout := 5000;
      Protocol := 1;
      ProtocolIPv6 := 0;
      PacketSize := 1024;
      Host:=HostT;
    end;
    IcmpClient.Ping(HostT,Random(1024));
    if IcmpClient.ReplyStatus.BytesReceived=0 then
    begin
      SendMessage(FormG.Handle, WM_Msg_PS, Integer(HostT+'*'+IntToStr(1)+'#'), 0);
      ActiveServer:=False;
    end
    else
      ActiveServer:=True;
  finally
    IcmpClient.Free;
  end;

  if ActiveServer then
  begin
    TCPClient:=TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    try
      with TCPClient do
      begin
        Host:=HostT;
        Port:=PortT;
        try
          Connect;
          try
            IOHandler.WriteLn('salam');
            SendMessage(FormG.Handle, WM_Msg_PS, Integer(HostT+'*'+IntToStr(2)+'#'), 0);
          finally
            Disconnect;
          end;
        except
          SendMessage(FormG.Handle, WM_Msg_PS, Integer(HostT+'*'+IntToStr(3)+'#'), 0);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      TCPClient.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure PS_System(FormNameForMessage:TForm;HostP:string;PortP:Integer);
var
  PSThread:TPSThread;
begin
  HostG:=HostP;
  PortG:=PortP;
  FormG:=FormNameForMessage;
  PSThread:=TPSThread.Create(false);
  PSThread.FreeOnTerminate:=true;
  PSThread.Resume;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  PS_System(form1,Edit1.Text,4321);
  PS_System(form1,Edit2.Text,4321);
  PS_System(form1,Edit3.Text,4321);
  PS_System(form1,Edit4.Text,4321);
  PS_System(form1,Edit5.Text,4321);
end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var Id:byte;
    Ip:string;
begin
  if Message.Msg= WM_Msg_PS then
  begin
    Ip:=copy(String(Message.WParam),1,pos('*',String(Message.WParam))-1);
    id:=strtoint(copy(String(Message.WParam),pos('*',String(Message.WParam))+1,(pos('#',String(Message.WParam))-pos('*',String(Message.WParam))-1)));
    case id of
      1:
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add(' Server '+ip+' Is inactive ');
          //ShowMessage(' Server '+ip+' Is inactive ');
        end;
      2:
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add(' Message was sent successfully to server '+ip);
          //ShowMessage(' Message was sent successfully to server '+ip);
        end;
      3:
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add(' Send message to the server fails '+ip);
          //ShowMessage(' Send message to the server fails '+ip);
        end;
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

**Program 2**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient,
  IdRawBase,IdRawClient, IdIcmpClient, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,StdCtrls,ExtCtrls;

type
  TPSThread=class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure execute; override;
end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  PortG:Integer;
  HostG:string;
  WM_Msg_PS:DWORD;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure IsInactiveServer(M:string);
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(' Server '+M+' Is inactive ');
  //ShowMessage(' Server '+M+' Is inactive ');
end;

procedure SentSuccessfullyToServer(M:string);
begin
   Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(' Message was sent successfully to server '+M);
   //ShowMessage(' Message was sent successfully to server '+M);
end;

procedure SendMessageFails(M:string);
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(' Send message to the server fails '+M);
  //ShowMessage(' Send message to the server fails '+M);
end;

procedure TPSThread.execute;
var
  IcmpClient:TIdIcmpClient;
  TCPClient:TIdTCPClient;
  HostT:string;
  PortT:Integer;
  ActiveServer:Boolean;
begin
  inherited;
  HostT:=HostG;
  PortT:=PortG;

  IcmpClient:= TIdIcmpClient.Create();
  try
    with IcmpClient do
    begin
      ReceiveTimeout := 5000;
      Protocol := 1;
      ProtocolIPv6 := 0;
      PacketSize := 1024;
      Host:=HostT;
    end;
    IcmpClient.Ping(HostT,Random(1024));
    if IcmpClient.ReplyStatus.BytesReceived=0 then
    begin
      IsInactiveServer(HostT);
      ActiveServer:=False;
    end
    else
      ActiveServer:=True;
  finally
    IcmpClient.Free;
  end;

  if ActiveServer then
  begin
    TCPClient:=TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    try
      with TCPClient do
      begin
        Host:=HostT;
        Port:=PortT;
        try
          Connect;
          try
            IOHandler.WriteLn('salam');
            SentSuccessfullyToServer(HostT);
          finally
            Disconnect;
          end;
        except
          SendMessageFails(HostT);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      TCPClient.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure PS_System(HostP:string;PortP:Integer);
var
  PSThread:TPSThread;
begin
  HostG:=HostP;
  PortG:=PortP;
  PSThread:=TPSThread.Create(false);
  PSThread.FreeOnTerminate:=true;
  PSThread.Resume;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  PS_System(Edit1.Text,4321);
  PS_System(Edit2.Text,4321);
  PS_System(Edit3.Text,4321);
  PS_System(Edit4.Text,4321);
  PS_System(Edit5.Text,4321);
end;

end.
```

---

Thank you
But my problem is not the ping
The my problem is the send message.
They also interfere with the thread send message.
If the parts do I remove my ping. Again there is the added problem.

Comment: Does this compile?  TThread.Execute() is abstract - you cannot call 'inherited' in your descendant 'TPSThread.execute'.  Do you not get an error from the compiler?

Comment: @Martin Compiler just ignores `inherited` when the base class method is abstract. No problems there.

Comment: Well, that's very nice of it. C++/C# moans at every opportunity if I try to do anything imperfect with abstract methods :(

Comment: There are all sorts of problems in both programs. You basically need to learn all about multi-threaded programming. It's beyond the remit of a Stack Overflow question to teach you that. I suggest that, at the very least, you should pick just one of your programs and let's see if we can show you what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 5):

Does this compile? TThread.Execute() is abstract - you cannot call 'inherited' in your descendant 'TPSThread.execute'. Do you not get an error from the compiler?

Creating your TPSThread with 'CreateSuspended' as false means that the thread may run 'immediately'. Setting fields after the Create call may not be effective.

Continually creating and destroying threads is wasteful, inefficient and prone to errors. Try hard not to do it.

If you want your four 'PS_System' calls to perform the network ping operations in a different thread, (so as not to block the main thread),  but in sequential order, you should queue the output requests off to one thread that is waiting on a producer-consumer queue to perform them.

Performing ICMP operations in parallel on seperate threads can be problematic since ICMP has no socket layer. PING replies may not be returned to the same thread that issued the request.  There is a workaround - the ping payload may contain the requesting thread ID and a 'routing' layer in the ICMP component can work out which waiting thread to make ready.  I don't know if the Indy ICMP has implemented this.

The helper procedures that are called from the thread add text to the GUI thread directly.  You cannot do that - you must signal correctly.

Multi-threaded PING example, (TCP connection obviously fails - I have no server):

```
unit foPinger;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons, ExtCtrls, SyncObjs,Contnrs, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdRawBase, IdRawClient, IdIcmpClient, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient;

type

EthreadRequest=(EtcDoPing,EtcReport,EtcError,EtcSuicide);

TpingRequest=class(TObject)  // a thread comms object
  command:EthreadRequest;
  hostName:string;
  port:string;
  reportText:string;
  errorMess:string;
end;

pObject=^Tobject;

TsemaphoreMailbox=class(TobjectQueue)  // Producer-consumer queue
private
  countSema:Thandle;
protected
  access:TcriticalSection;
public
  property semaHandle:Thandle read countSema;
  constructor create; virtual;
  procedure push(aObject:Tobject); virtual;
  function pop(pResObject:pObject;timeout:DWORD):boolean;  virtual;
  function peek(pResObject:pObject):boolean;  virtual;
  destructor destroy; override;
end;

TPSThread=class(TThread)   // The thread to try the network comms
  private
    FinQueue:TsemaphoreMailbox;
    IcmpClient:TIdIcmpClient;
    TCPClient:TIdTCPClient;
    ActiveServer:Boolean;
    FmyForm:TForm;
  protected
    procedure execute; override;
  public
    constructor create(myForm:TForm;inputQueue:TsemaphoreMailbox);
    procedure postToMain(mess:TpingRequest);
    procedure postReport(text:string);
end;

  TpingerForm = class(TForm)                    // main form
    Panel1: TPanel;
    sbPing1: TSpeedButton;
    ebHostName: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    ebPort: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    ebThreadCount: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure sbPing1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ebThreadCountChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    threadCount:integer;
    queueToThreads:TsemaphoreMailbox;
  protected
    procedure WMAPP(var message:Tmessage); message WM_APP;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  pingerForm: TpingerForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TsemaphoreMailbox }

constructor TsemaphoreMailbox.create;
begin
   inherited Create;
  access:=TcriticalSection.create;
  countSema:=createSemaphore(nil,0,maxInt,nil);
end;

destructor TsemaphoreMailbox.destroy;
begin
  access.free;
  closeHandle(countSema);
  inherited;
end;

function TsemaphoreMailbox.pop(pResObject: pObject;
  timeout: DWORD): boolean;
// dequeues an object, if one is available on the queue.  If the queue is empty,
// the caller is blocked until either an object is pushed on or the timeout
// period expires
begin // wait for a unit from the semaphore
  result:=(WAIT_OBJECT_0=waitForSingleObject(countSema,timeout));
  if result then // if a unit was supplied before the timeout,
  begin
    access.acquire;
    try
      pResObject^:=inherited pop; // get an object from the queue
    finally
      access.release;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TsemaphoreMailbox.push(aObject: Tobject);
// pushes an object onto the queue.  If threads are waiting in a 'pop' call,
// one of them is made ready.
begin
  access.acquire;
  try
    inherited push(aObject); // shove the object onto the queue
  finally
    access.release;
  end;
  releaseSemaphore(countSema,1,nil); // release one unit to semaphore
end;

function TsemaphoreMailbox.peek(pResObject: pObject): boolean;
begin
  access.acquire;
  try
    result:=(Count>0);
    if result then pResObject^:=inherited pop; // get an object from the queue
  finally
    access.release;
  end;
end;

{ TPSThread }

constructor TPSThread.create(myForm:TForm;inputQueue:TsemaphoreMailbox);
begin
  inherited create(true);
  FmyForm:=myForm;
  FinQueue:=inputQueue;
  FreeOnTerminate:=true;
  Resume;
end;

procedure TPSThread.postToMain(mess:TpingRequest);
begin
  PostMessage(FmyForm.Handle,WM_APP,integer(FmyForm),integer(mess));
end;

procedure TPSThread.postReport(text:string);
var reportMess:TpingRequest;
begin
  reportMess:=TpingRequest.Create;
  reportMess.command:=EtcReport;
  reportMess.reportText:=text;
  postToMain(reportMess);
end;


procedure TPSThread.execute;
var inMess:TpingRequest;
  ActiveServer:Boolean;

    procedure tryConnect;
    begin
        with IcmpClient do
        begin
          ReceiveTimeout := 5000;
          Protocol := 1;
          ProtocolIPv6 := 0;
          PacketSize := 1024;
          Host:=inMess.hostName;
        end;
        IcmpClient.Ping(inMess.hostName,Random(1024));
        if IcmpClient.ReplyStatus.BytesReceived=0 then
        begin
          inMess.errorMess:=('PING failed');
          ActiveServer:=False;
        end
        else
          ActiveServer:=True;

      if ActiveServer then
      begin
          with TCPClient do
          begin
            Host:=inMess.hostName;
            Port:=strToInt(inMess.port);
            try
              Connect;
              try
                IOHandler.WriteLn('salam');
                inMess.reportText:='Message was sent successfully to server';
              finally
                Disconnect;
              end;
            except
              on e:exception do
              begin
                inMess.errorMess:=('TCP connection failed : '+e.Message);
              end;
            end;
          end;
      end;
    end;

begin
  postReport('PING thread started');
  IcmpClient:= TIdIcmpClient.Create();  // make Indy components
  TCPClient:=TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    while FinQueue.pop(@inMess,INFINITE) do  // wait for message
    begin
      try
        case inMess.command of               // switch on command in message
          EtcDoPing: tryConnect;
          EtcSuicide: begin
                        inMess.command:=EtcReport;
                        inMess.reportText:='Thread exit';
                        exit;
                      end;
        else
          begin
            inMess.command:=EtcError;;
            inMess.errorMess:='Command not understood in PSThread';
          end;
        end;
      finally
        postToMain(inMess);                  // send message back with results
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IcmpClient.Free; // free off all the stuff made in ctor
    TCPClient.Free;
  end;
end;

{ TpingerForm }

procedure TpingerForm.ebThreadCountChange(Sender: TObject);
var newThreads:integer;
    suicideMess:TpingRequest;
begin
  try
    newThreads:=strToInt(ebThreadCount.Text);
    while threadCount<newThreads do
    begin
      TPSThread.create(self,queueToThreads);
      inc(threadCount);
    end;
    while threadCount>newThreads do
    begin
      suicideMess:=TpingRequest.Create;
      suicideMess.command:=EtcSuicide;
      queueToThreads.push(suicideMess);
      dec(threadCount);
    end;
  except;
  end;
end;

procedure TpingerForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var editThreadCount:integer;
begin
  queueToThreads:=TsemaphoreMailbox.create;
  editThreadCount:=strToInt(ebThreadCount.Text);
  while(threadCount<editThreadCount) do // make initial number of threads
  begin
    TPSThread.create(self,queueToThreads);
    inc(threadCount);
  end;
end;

procedure TpingerForm.sbPing1Click(Sender: TObject);
var outMess:TpingRequest;
begin
  outMess:=TpingRequest.Create;  // make a thread comms object
  outMess.command:=EtcDoPing;    // fill up
  outMess.hostName:=ebHostName.Text;
  outMess.port:=ebPort.Text;
  queueToThreads.push(outMess);
end;

// Message-handler for messages from thread
procedure TpingerForm.WMAPP(var message: Tmessage);
var inMess:TpingRequest;

  procedure messReport;
  begin
    memo1.Lines.Add(inMess.reportText);
  end;

  procedure messError;
  begin
    memo1.Lines.Add('>*Error*< '+inMess.errorMess);
  end;

  procedure messPing;
  var reportOut:string;
  begin
    reportOut:='Host '+inMess.hostName+', port: '+inMess.port+', ';
    if (inMess.errorMess='') then
       reportOut:=reportOut+'comms OK'
    else
      begin
        reportOut:=reportOut+'comms failed: '+inMess.ErrorMess;
      end;
      memo1.Lines.Add(reportOut);
      memo1.Lines.Add('');
  end;

begin
  inMess:=TpingRequest(message.LParam);
  try
    case inMess.command of
      EtcReport: messReport;
      EtcError: messError;
      EtcDoPing:messPing;
    end;
  finally
    inMess.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

[image: Pinger working with 10 threads]

Answer (score 2):

When writing code with threads, you need to understand the the execution order is not guaranteed, as a matter of a fact ,when programming in multi-thread, you should know that code that is not locked(synchronized) could be executed and cause non safe calls and cause data to behave not as expected.

Please read more on threads and understand the case of [critical section thread synchronization](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/op4.htm) is a good place to start.

if you need execution order ,then do all the calculation before the printing, wait for all the threads to finish, and then do all the printing. The Downside of this order ,is not real time printing, however, you get clean output.

Comment: Thank you
But my problem is not the ping
The my problem is the send message.
They also interfere with the thread send message.
If the parts do I remove my ping. Again there is the added problem.

Comment: if you want to order the send messages, make one thread send messages, one thread print.